# Automatically convert date text to correct date format using Google Sheets

Tags: date, google-sheets, formula

I'm trying to convert date from "text" to correct format. It is logged to Google Spreadsheets and I'm unable to use it to plot graphs.

This is the text format: `February 3, 2018, at 11:21 AM`

Time is not relevant, all I need is the date converted: `DD/MM/YYYY.`

I found a similar question where Gary's Student answered with a formula that looks like this for a different format:

```
=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-2,2),""))
```

([link to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38634547/convert-text-date-format-to-date-format))

How can I use above formula (or something similar) so that text is converted to date?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Google Sheets or Excel?  You have tags for both, but your title says Google Sheets, but the link you included is to an Excel question.  The two are similar but not the same.  I would suggest (once you decide which platform you're using), just copy & paste your question's title into a search engine to find an answer.  See also [mcve] and [ask], as well as [help/on-topic].  You can [edit] your question to provide clarification as needed,.

Comment: Hi - I'm using Google Sheets. I've removed Excel tag. Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `, at` portion of the string is keeping Google Sheets from recognizing it as a datevalue. Just remove it with the substitute function and wrap in datevalue function like so: `=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,", at",""))`

To format as `DD/MM/YYYY` just go to custom formatting and set it to look like the following:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

```
=DATEVALUE(JOIN("/", LEFT(D5,2), {MID(D5,4,2), RIGHT(D5,4)}))
```

where D5 contains for example: `25.06.2019`

which script converts to datevalue: `43641`

Dateformat is as `dd.MM.YYYY` converted to `dd/MM/YYYY` and then converted to datevalue.

Google sheet's documentation helps:

[`DATEVALUE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093039?hl=en), [`JOIN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=en), [`LEFT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094079?hl=en), [`MID`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094129?hl=en), [`RIGHT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094087?hl=en)

Datevalue is useful for organizing rows of data by date correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to create custom function.

1. Open `tools` → `script editor` in menu to open script editor in new tab
2. Click `Untitled project` in top left corner and rename
3. Open `Resources` → `Libraries` in top menu
4. Paste library key `MHMchiX6c1bwSqGM1PZiW_PxhMjh3Sh48` and click `Add` to add the `Moment` library to your script
5. Choose `Moment` version `9` and click `Save`
6. Paste function

```js
function parseDate(dateString, format){
  return Moment.moment(dateString, format).toDate()
}
```

to `Code.gs` and save project `Ctrl+S`

Now you use your function in any cell in your sheet:

```
=parseDate(B2,"MMM D, YYYY, at HH:mm A")
```

more details about format:
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/

You can also create function to display date in custom format:

```js
function formatDate(date, format){
  return Moment.moment(date).format(format)
}
```

Use it like this in cell

```
=formatDate(B5,"DD/MM/YYYY")
```

or

```
=formatDate(parseDate(B2,"MMM D, YYYY, at HH:mm A"),"DD/MM/YYYY")
```

Comment: Nice solution. Since I don't know who & what's behind the library key in the solution, I loaded moment.js from CDN as outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33315754/2258093